# Running room DB inside AsyncTask gives an error

Tags: android, multithreading, android-room

Hi I am running some operation that copies data drom Firebase DB to local room DB.
Here is doInBackground part from my AsyncTask.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        contactList = getContactListFromPhone();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    if (contactList.containsKey(user.getPhone()))
                    {

                        UserDB userDB = new UserDB();
                        userDB.setName(user.getName());
                        userDB.setPhone(user.getPhone());
                        userDB.setToken(user.getToken());


                        //adding to database
                        DatabaseClient.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).getAppDatabase().userDao().insert(userDB);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



        return null;
    }
```

But on line "DatabaseClient.getInstance...." I receiving an error:

```
Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time
```

But I am already in AsyncTask, why is that?

Comment: It's not about AsyncTask but about Firebase. Firebase's `onDataChange` will be callen in MainThread and hence you DatabaseClient.getInstance is running in MainThread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about **AsyncTask** but about **Firebase**. Firebase's `onDataChange` will be called in the MainThread and hence you `DatabaseClient.getInstance` is running in the MainThread.

You don't have to perform your Firebase calls in separate thread as Firebase client deals with it. But when you get a response from Firebase, it's `onDataChange` will be performed in the `MainThread`.

I suggest you to call Firebase in the MainThread and then after getting the data in `onDataChanged`, call your AsyncTask that has calls `DatabaseClient.getInstance`.